# Scale the data for cluster analysis

Tags: time-series, hierarchical-clustering, copula

I have a time-series data. I would like to use (hierarchical) cluster analysis for them. I read that I need to scale my data. My question is, can I use empirical function (transfer the data into (0,1)) in order to get the scale of my data?!. That is, can I use copula data as a scale data?

For example: Suppose I would like to use **iris** data set. Then, to use the cluster method, I need to scale my data. In this case, is it correct to transfer **iris** to copula data using empirical function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling the data for clustering can be done using `scale` function. However, transforming the data into copula data will not scale your data.